# Excel checkbox in the center of cell

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, position, center

Is it possible to move box of checkbox to center of the cell? I am creating checkbox. Checkbox itself is on the left side and text is on the right side. I am deleting text so there is only "checkbox" left. I want the whole area of the cell to be "clickable". So if I resize the field, clickable area will be smaller. Is there any way to keep the size of checkbox the same as cell size and move checkbox box to the middle/center? Like for the text there is button to position text on the left, center and right?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty straightforward. You have to get the `Top` and `Left` positions of the cell you'd like to center the checkbox. So...

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Sub CenterMyCheckbox()
    Dim myCheckbox As Shape
    Set myCheckbox = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1")
        
    Dim cbCell As Range
    Set cbCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B3")
        
    '--- this just positions the checkbox even with the top, left of the cell
    myCheckbox.left = cbCell.left
    myCheckbox.top = cbCell.top
       
    '--- this centers the checkbox vertically
    Dim cellHeight As Double
    Dim cbHeight As Double
    cellHeight = cbCell.Height
    cbHeight = myCheckbox.Height
    myCheckbox.top = cbCell.top + (cellHeight / 2#) - (cbHeight / 2#)
End Sub
```